# assertEquals between objects of inconvertible String and Optional<String> JUnit test

Tags: java, junit, java-8, junit4

I am trying to test a Java 8 optional but when I hover over the `assertEquals` it says `Equals between objects of inconvertible String and Optional<String>`

```
@Test
    @Sql({"applicant.sql"})
    public void findbySSN() throws Exception {
        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000000008");

        assertNotNull(tApplicant.getIndSsn());
        assertEquals("N",tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd());

    }
```

I am not quite sure on how to handle this.

In the class the method looks like `public Optional<String> getAsvabScrTypCd() { return Optional.ofNullable(asvabScrTypCd);}`

------------------------Update 1-------------------------

It has been brought to my attention AssertJ might be the answer however it is not recognizing `.isNotEmpty());` or `.hasValue("N");`

I double check and I have the maven dependency :

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
         <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>

@Test
    @Sql({"applicant.sql"})
    public void findbySSN() throws Exception {
        TApplicant tApplicant;

        tApplicant = applicant.findbySSN("000000008");

        assertNotNull(tApplicant.getIndSsn());

        assertThat(tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd().isNotEmpty());
        assertThat(tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd()).hasValue("N");
    }
```

There is a similar post [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38954742/assert-that-optional-has-certain-value) but did not help me.

Comment: @jjst yes this is a possible duplicate but the answer is not working. Please see my update.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to use AssertJ. The [second answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38958484/887422) from the post I linked should be of help. The simplest way to test whether the Optional contains your expected value is to call `Optional.get()`:

```
assertEquals("N", tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd().get());
```

Or alternatively, using `Optional.of()`:

```
assertEquals(Optional.of("N"), tApplicant.getAsvabScrTypCd());
```

See the post I linked to for other options. It is generally a good idea to avoid calling `Optional.get()` directly, as it will throw an exception, and the whole point of `Optional` is to move error checking for nullables from runtime to compile time. That said, this is arguably less of an issue for test code.